# Dompdf unicode problem

Tags: unicode, dompdf

Is there any solution for dompdf unicode.

Comment: You should indicate which release of DOMPDF you are using. The 0.6.0 release will include Unicode support. There is a document on the DOMPDF site outlining [how to enable Unicode support](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode).

Answer (score 0):

Dompdf utf problem is mainly about fonts. If you can supply your own fonts or use something like DejaVu which has contains large set of chars. Edit the information your fonts in config file dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php.

Get your language special characters in ASCII numerical code and replace like that, in this example Turkish special chars

```
$from = array('İ', 'ı', 'Ö', 'ö', 'Ü', 'ü', 'Ç', 'ç', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ş', 'ş');
$to   = array('&#304;', '&#305;', '&#214;', '&#246;', ' &#220;', '&#252;', '&#199;', '&#231;', '&#286;', '&#287;', '&#350;', '&#351;');
$html= str_replace($from, $to, $html);
```

Your output should looks good without weird chars.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is not. I would go with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) but that requires access on the box. Other options are [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) and others spawned from the same fpdf (but these don't convert HTML to PDF, but rather supply you with some primitives for creating a PDF). Again, I would go with wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Actually, DOMPDF will include Unicode support for the 0.6.0 release (currently in beta, but fairly stable). You can't go wrong with wkhtmltopdf if you can use it, but DOMPDF is making head-way in this area.